# CPP string constructor find and append null characters

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

In C++ `strings` are copied until a `NULL`  character is received while feeding in a sequence of characters. But if you supply the number of characters to be read, will it copy past the `NULL` character? I have a situation where I may receive a message that has a NULL character in the middle and still useful information after it. The same question applies to append.

Similarly for `find()`, will it stop searching if it hits a `NULL`  character?

Comment: If you are speaking of `std::string` then yes, they can have \0 in the middle. std::string don't use the "ended by \0" convention. They have memory for storing the size. So they can be used as buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to construct a string containing the `'\0'` character:

```
const char a[] = "Hello\0world";
std::string s(a, sizeof(a));

std::cout << "a = \"" << a << "\"\n";
std::cout << "s = \"" << s << "\"\n";
std::cout << "sizeof(a)  = " << sizeof(a) << '\n';
std::cout << "strlen(a)  = " << std::strlen(a) << '\n';
std::cout << "s.length() = " << s.length() << '\n';
```

The above snippet will print

```
a = "Hello"
s = "Helloworld"
sizeof(a)  = 12
strlen(a)  = 5
s.length() = 12
```

Comment: Does the output of s also contain the null char or does it just drop the null char?

Comment: @legion That is a good question that I don't know the answer to at the moment. Will have to check it.

Comment: Interesting results! `std::string` doesn't know `\0` as a string terminator! _Poor C-style strings_ :-D

Comment: @legion According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), the output operator for string calls [`std::basic_streambuf::sputn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputn) with the whole string, including the embedded `'\0'`. My guess is that the `'\0'` is dropped after the library have written the string to the operating system.

Comment: @MM. `std::string` doesn't care about the C-style terminator, it has its length instead. If you don't provide a length on construction, then of course the string will infer it from finding the C-style terminator character.